# regex match saving

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex, how do I save the value of `\1` into another variable?

```
image_id = A8064ABAAAGAAT120108.1
version = re.sub(r'^.*?(\d+\D*)(\..*)', r'\1T\2', image_id)
```

Comment: Match it rather than substitute it.

Comment: @Marius and hexparrot - I mean to say save it in another varilable ..i want to check if the first match (\1) is >=8 and then add some logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better match the regex in the string:

```
pattern = re.compile('.*?(\d+\D*)(\..*)')
k = pattern.search(image_id)
saved_value = k.groups()[0] # this will give you the value 
                            # of the fist matched group
                            # as a string
```